# I am very confused about net acceleration and angular acceleration in circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, rotational-kinematics

I have seen in many places that angular acceleration can be zero but net acceleration can't be zero in circular motion. I want to know whose components are tangential and radial acceleration (net or angular acceleration) and what is the significance of angular acceleration then?
After studying axial vectors like angular displacement, angular velocity, angular acceleration why shift to net acceleration which is in plane(I think)
(Please correct me wherever I am wrong I am new to this concept)

Comment: "...why shift to..." What do you mean by "shift to"? In circular motion the *angular* acceleration can be zero, without the total ("net") acceleration being zero. This is because there is a *radial* component to acceleration too. The magnitude of the acceleration is not zero in circular motion at constant velocity because there must be a radial component to change the *direction* of the velocity at every moment (even if the magnitude of the velocity is constant).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a movement on a plane, described by the position vector $\mathbf{r} = r \mathbf{\hat{r}}$ (note that this unit vector points from the origin to the particle/object). Using the kinematic derivative rules $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{\hat{r}} = \dot{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}$ and  $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{\hat{\theta}} = -\dot{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{r}}$, you get by differentiating position the velocity (chain rule!):
$$
\mathbf{v} = \dot{r} \mathbf{\hat{r}} + r\dot{\theta} \mathbf{\hat{\theta}}
$$
and differentiating once again, we get acceleration:
$$
\mathbf{a} = (\ddot{r} - r\dot{\theta}^2)\mathbf{\hat{r}} + (2\dot{r}\dot{\theta} + r \ddot{\theta})\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}
$$

This is the most general case and there's velocity and acceleration in both radial $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ and tangential $\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}$ directions. When the movement is circular, the radius $r$ has no derivatives of any order (doesn't change), se the above definitions are now:
$$
\mathbf{v} = r\dot{\theta} \mathbf{\hat{\theta}}
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{a} = - r\dot{\theta}^2\mathbf{\hat{r}} + r \ddot{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}
$$
that is, velocity is always tangent to the (circular) trajectory but acceleration has a radially inward centripetal component! it is also usual to relabel $\dot{\theta} = \omega$ (angular velocity) and $\ddot{\theta} = \dot{\omega} = \alpha$ (angular acceleration). Now you can say:
$$
\mathbf{a} = - r\omega^2\mathbf{\hat{r}} + r \alpha\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}
$$
That is, acceleration has both radial/centripetal and tangential components, and the tangential component is related to the angular acceleration by $a_{\text{tangent}} = r \alpha$.

Finally, you can let $\alpha = 0$ and there will still be some component to acceleration.

Comment: Also, when α=0, the speed remains the same as it goes around the circle. When not, the speed of the object increases or decreases over time.